# can css grid-template-rows have fractional units with decimals?

Tags: css

```
<section class="advertised">
        <div class="zx9-display">
          <!-- <img src="/audiophile/assets/home/desktop/image-speaker-zx9.png" class="speaker-photo" alt="zx9 speaker" /> -->
          <div class="zx9-content">
            <h2 class="ad-title">ZX9 SPEAKER</h2>
            <p class="ad-content">Upgrade to premium speakers that are phenomenally built to deliver truly remarkable sound.</p>
            <button class="zx9-btn">SEE PRODUCT</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="zx7-display">
          <div class="zx7-content">
            <h2 class="zx7-title">ZX7 SPEAKER</h2>
            <button class="product-btn"><a href="/zx7-speaker.html">SEE PRODUCT</a></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="yx1-display">
          <div class="yx1-earphones">
            <img src="/audiophile/assets/home/desktop/image-earphones-yx1.jpg" class="earphone-photo" alt="yx1 earphones" />
          </div>
          <div class="yx1-content">
            <h2 class="yx1-title">YX1 EARPHONES</h2>
            <button class="product-btn"><a href="/yx1.html">SEE PRODUCT</a></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

```
.advertised {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1.72fr 1fr 1fr;
    row-gap: 10rem;
  }

  /* zx9 graphic display ad */
  
.zx9-display{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1.9fr;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #D87D4A
  }

  .zx9-content {
    grid-column: 2;
    display: grid;
    max-width: 21.8125rem;
    max-height: 18.9375rem;
  }

  .ad-title {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 3.625rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .ad-content {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    line-height: 1.5625rem;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.75;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  }

  .zx9-btn {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }[![figma file[![audiophile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psuyf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psuyf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8O4a.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8O4a.png)
```

I have been trying to use css grid to correctly place the contents as guided by the figma file. But I have been told to use fractional units instead of widths and heights. I was using rem and em for grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows to place everything correctly. but I was told not to and to use fr. what I want to know is if there is a way that I can convert em to fr. also what is the opinion of using rem and em instead of fr
example :
grid-template-columns: 27rem 27rem;
I was also thinking of just using grid-template-columns: auto auto;
and adjust the content.

Comment: You could use `172fr 100fr 100fr;`, `30fr 19fr` etc.

Comment: No, rem and fr do fundamentally different things and can't be substituted for each other. The remainder of your question is opinion-based and so off-topic.